# True or False in Excel show as checkbox in datagridview

Tags: c#, excel, linq, datagridview

I have an excel file with a column that has true or false (text) in it but after I imported the file, the column that has true or false show as checkbox column in datagridview instead of the text itself.

How to fix this? Is this something to do with Excel?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It has to do with datagridview dsiplaying a boolean type.  the DGV automatically converts a boolean to a checkbox.  Are you using a DataTable or manually loading the DGV.

Comment: I manually load the DGV

Comment: Then make column text instead of boolean and load with string not true/false.

Comment: Okay, thanks. But is it possible that the DGV will not automatically converts a boolean to a checkbox?

Comment: I don't think so.

Comment: Not correct - you can achieve this.  I have seen it.  My issue is that I do not know the conditions on which it occurs.

Comment: To elaborate on my last comment,  What I can tell you is that when you use Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0, the data is presented in a way that booleans are handled as checkboxes in datagridview.  That said there are conditions that may be created in an excel cpreadsheet (likely due to missing information) that cause errors when trying to load the file using the Ace driver.

Answer (score 0):

This is an old question but I wanted to post a response in case someone runs into the same issue.  I had the opposite issue - I had text TRUE / FALSE as a string and wanted it to be a Boolean/checkbox in my datagridview
In your case, you need to change the data type of the column in question.
This can be achieved by doing something like this

Let's assume for a minute that you have a data table 4 rows x 4 columns and you know that the first column one is a boolean type

```
private DataTable change_frombool_tostring(DataTable newDataTable)
{
    // take a copy of your original datatable
    int i = 0;
    DataTable newDataTable = originalDataTable.Clone();
    foreach (DataColumn dc in newDataTable.Columns)
    {
        // if you want to make a change to column 0 in your data table
        if (i == 0) 
        {
            // the data type for a boolean is typeof(bool) - we need to change it
            dc.DataType = typeof(string);
        }
       //Alternatively, if you wanted all boolean columns to be shown as a string, you could check each columns datatype then do 
        if (dc.DataType == System.Boolean) 
        {
            dc.DataType = typeof(string)
        }
    }
    foreach (DataRow dr in originalDataTable.Rows)
    {
        newDataTable.ImportRow(dr);
    }
    return newDataTable:
}
```

In closing, a datatype of a column determines how a cell in a column is presented.